# Controller not found issue when rewriting url with exclamation mark

Tags: castle-monorail

In monorail I'm trying to create a url rewriting rule to give friendly urls to article posts. Here's what the urls look like:

http://domain.com/2010/11/29/Winter-snow-warning

And here's the code in global.asax.cs to rewrite the urls:

```
RoutingModuleEx.Engine.Add(
                new PatternRoute("/<year>/<month>/<day>/<title>")
                    .DefaultForController().Is("post")
                    .DefaultForAction().Is("show")
                    .Restrict("year").ValidInteger
                    .Restrict("month").ValidInteger
                    .Restrict("day").ValidInteger
            );
```

This works great, however if there is an exclamation point in the url:

http://domain.com/2010/11/29/Winter-snow-warning!!

Then it doesn't match the rewriting rule and errors out, saying the controller "2010" cannot be found. What am I missing here, is this a bug in monorail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the default matching mechanism of Monorail's routing is not accepting exclamation mark, thus the route does not match and the default `/controller/action` rule is matched instead, failing since no 2010 controller exists.

A quick workaround could be to to restrict the title to the exact expression that fits your needs. e.g.: `.Restring("title").ValidRegex("[-_.+!*'() a-zA-Z0-9]+]")`